# pytest - use plugin from another plugin

Tags: python, plugins, pytest, allure

I made a new plugin using this [repo](https://github.com/pytest-dev/cookiecutter-pytest-plugin/) with [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) and i want to use another plugin from it.

for example:
when I run `pytest --useplugin`

this should run :`pytest --anotherplugin=12345 --useplugin`

(more command line arguments run in the background.)

I didn't find anything in pytest documentation.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to see whether `anotherplugin` provides a pytest hook for you to use. If it does, you can use following in your code:

```
@pytest.mark.optionalhook 
def optional_hook_name
```

If it does not provide a hook, you may have to use [suitable pytest hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html)  to pass relevant arguments. Be cautious, passing argument to another plugin using unsuitable pytest hooks may sometime cause race around condition.